# return gender by the country from my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
name   country    gender
wang    ca         1
jay     us         1
jay     ca         0
jay     ca         1
lisa    en         0
lisa    us         1
```

I want to assign the gender based on code 'US'. If the name is same, then all the gender should be the same as gender assigned to code us. For name that has no duplicate, we return the same row.

The return result should be

```
name    code   gender
wang     ca     1
jay      us     1
lisa     us     1
```

I used

```
df.gropuby(['name', 'country'])['gender'].transform()
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: is there only one row for each name/country?  If not, how do you want gender defined?

Comment: if the 'country' is US, and there are duplicate names, all gender follows the US gender. If no duplicate names, the row remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get country and gender in separate lists for a name
a = df.groupby('name')['country'].apply(list).reset_index(name='country_list')
b = df.groupby('name')['gender'].apply(list).reset_index(name='gender_list')

# Merge 
df2 = a.merge(b, on='name', how='left')

# Using apply get final required values
def get_val(x):
    cl, gl = x
    final = [cl[0], gl[0]]
    for c,g in zip(cl,gl):
        if c=='us':
            final.append(c)
            final.append(g)
    return final

df2['final_col'] = df2[['country_list', 'gender_list']].apply(get_val, axis=1) 
df2['code'] = df2['final_col'].apply(lambda l: l[0])
df2['gender'] = df2['final_col'].apply(lambda l: l[1])
print(df2)
```

Comment: I am not sure...as your logic to calculate `gender` is not straightforward..so you may have to construct your own using `apply` function.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I've used is a `merge()` followed by a conditional replace (`np.where()`)

It's a bit more sophisticated but will work for conditions not it your sample data.

```
import io
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""name   country    gender
wang    ca         1
jay     us         1
jay     ca         0
jay     ca         1
lisa    en         0
lisa    us         1"""), sep="\s+")

# use "us" as basis for lookup. left merge on name only
df2 = (df.merge(df.query("country=='us'"), 
          on=["name"], how="left", suffixes=("", "_new"))
 # replace only where it's not "us" and "us" has a different value
 .assign(gender=lambda x: np.where((x["country"]!="us")&
                                   (x["gender"]!=x["gender_new"])&
                                   ~(x["gender_new"].isna())
                                   # force type casting so it doesn't become float64 because of NaN
                                   , x["gender_new"].fillna(-1).astype("int64"), 
                                    x["gender"]))
 # remove columns inserted by merge...
 .drop(columns=["country_new", "gender_new"])
)
```

**output**

```
 name country  gender
 wang      ca       1
  jay      us       1
  jay      ca       1
  jay      ca       1
 lisa      en       1
 lisa      us       1
```

Comment: it is a one liner... I've separated onto multi lines for readability.  no looping plus very defensive conditions to guarantee it will always work.